# Random Characters in pseudocode

Tags: random

My assignment is to create in pseudocode a module that accepts a 200 element array of alpha characters.  How do I write the code to choose the 200 characters at random and put them in an array?

My full assignment is:

> Create a module in pseudocode which
>   accepts a 200 element array of
>   characters, determines the number of
>   occurrences of each of the five vowels
>   in the array (a, e, i, o, u), and
>   prints the number of occurrences of
>   each vowel to the screen.  [25 pts]

I am sure there is an easier way of putting this but this is what I figured out:

```
Module vowels(characterArray)
    Declare Boolean found
    Declare Integer Index
    Declare Integer vowelA
    Declare Integer vowelE
    Declare Integer vowelI
    Declare Integer vowelO
    Declare Integer vowelU
    Set found = false
    Set index = 0
    Set vowelA = 0
    Set vowelE = 0
    Set vowelI = 0
    Set vowelO = 0
    Set vowelU = 0
    While found == false AND index <= size – 1
        If characterArray[index] == ucase$(“a”)
            Set vowelA = vowelA + 1
            If characterArray[index] == ucase$( “e”)
                Set vowelE = vowelE + 1
                If characterArray[index] == ucase$( “i”)
                    Set vowelI = vowelI + 1
                    If characterArray[index] == ucase$( “o”)
                        Set vowelO = vowelO + 1
                        If characterArray[index] == ucase$( “u”)
                            Set vowelU = vowelU + 1
                        Else
                            Set found = true
                        Endif
                    Endif
                Endif
            Endif
        Endif
    Endwhile
        Display “Number of A’s: “ ,vowelA
        Display “Number of E’s: “ ,vowelE
        Display “Number of I’s: “ ,vowelI
        Display “Number of O’s: “ ,vowelO
        Display “Number of U’s: “ ,vowelU
End Module
```

Comment: Do you need to write a module that accepts the array or that creates the array?

Comment: The assignment doesn't ask you to generate the array, just to accept it as input.

Comment: i wanted to create an array that has the 26 letters of the alphabit but then i didnt know how to randomize that. 

accepts the array

Comment: oh wow good atch alistair...ive been at this for a few hours and getting tired

Comment: @Tara - your question essentially asks us to do your assignment for you. If you're tired, get some sleep and try again tomorrow. It's not going to be much use to you if we just do your entire assignment. If you get stuck on a particular aspect, then ask for further help.

Comment: nooo i just read it wrong, Im not asking for you to do it for me.  I am in the process of writing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not too far off.  As you have it coded right now, though, you'll only look for an 'e' if you've already found that the character is an 'a'.  Ditto for 'i', 'o', and 'u'.  Think about it step by step and you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to realize that there are 26 alphanumeric characters. So, generate a *number* between 1 and 26 (or 0 and 25), and convert that number to a letter between A and Z. Repeat 200 times to get a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about how you would write this with functions.  Also, you're not really using the `found` variable, assuming the variable size is equal to the size of the array.  In most languages, it's conventional to have the loop end condition be, not `index <= size – 1`, but rather `index < size`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more hints:

1. You need to iterate over the entire
   array (no need to break early)
2. Use a `switch` statement to simplify the if-else (incorrect) logic you have.
3. Handle lower and upper case vowels ('a' and 'A' have
   different values)